# How to set pageSize in collectionPagingDatasource

Tags: oracle-jet

Hey I'm using ojCollection to fetch limited records from database, I'm able to create a model and collection with that model. But I'm not clear on how to set the totalSize of fetched record and where to set it. Can some one please share the expected json structure of fetched data in order to get limited records as well as the total size in DB.

Basically I'm not using REST api in my project so it would be helpful if I get the json structure that collection api's are expecting.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the structure oracle-jet follows. limit represents pagination size, totalResults represents total number of records in db, hasMore to tell anymore records are present.

```
{
    "items": [
      {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
      }
    ],
    "totalResults": 8,
    "limit": 10,
    "offset": 0,
    "hasMore": "false"
}
```